# Auto wrap td every 4 columns

Tags: html, css

I have 8 td in my table and my problem is I would like to wrap the td every 4th column. So in short, I want the 5th td will display in new line. Please help me. Thanks.

```
<div id="schedule">
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>terdg</td>
            <td>yhr6t</td>
            <td>yhr6t</td>
            <td>yhr6t</td>

            <td>hgf</td>
            <td>gdrg</td>
            <td>tyht</td>
            <td>drf</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So close the row after the fourth td. What's the actual problem?

Comment: What do you need? I mean if you can show in some image / mockup.

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** retain the same HTML structure you can manage this with floats but  it's likely that you will lose the *"tableness"* of the cells and you may have to adjust accordingly.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

table {}

td {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="schedule">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
        <td>cell 5</td>
        <td>cell 6</td>
        <td>cell 7</td>
        <td>cell 8</td>
        <td>cell 9</td>
        <td>cell 10</td>
        <td>cell 11</td>
        <td>cell 12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div id="schedule">
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>terdg</td>
            <td>yhr6t</td>
            <td>yhr6t</td>
            <td>yhr6t</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hgf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>gdrg</td>
            <td>tyht</td>
            <td>drf</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```